# Checking Glassfish error log

Tags: java, servlets, logging, glassfish

I'm using NetBeans 7.2 and GlassFish 3.1.2 and I'm running a web application with JSPs and Servlets. There seems to be some errors in the output because I'm getting a blank webpage when the app is run. I understand that the log file is located in glassfish/domains/logs folder, but I'm not able to see any `System.out` or `System.err` inside of that text file.

Is there anything I have to configure so that I can read the log and come to know as to where I'm going wrong? Ideally I'm trying to debug the servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In NetBeans, go to Tools->Servers.  Select the GlassFish Server and on the 'common' tab the 'Domains folder' + the 'Domain Name' is the root folder you need to browse to on your machine.  Inside of that folder, you'll see a 'logs' folder which will contain the 'server.log' file.